# How to remove n number of identical characters from string in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have a string in R where the words are interspaced with a random number of character `\n`:

```
mystring = c("hello\n\ni\n\n\n\n\nam\na\n\n\n\n\n\n\ndog")
```

I want to replace n number of repeating `\n` elements so that there is only a space character between words. I can currently do this as follows, but I want a tidier solution:

```
 mystring %>% 
    gsub("\n\n", "\n", .) %>% 
    gsub("\n\n", "\n", .) %>% 
    gsub("\n\n", "\n", .) %>% 
    gsub("\n", " ", .)

[1] "hello i am a dog"
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `gsub("\\n{1,}", " ", mystring)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `+` to signify `one or more` repetitions

```
gsub("\n+", " ", mystring)
[1] "hello i am a dog"
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use same logic as akrun with `str_replace_all`:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(mystring, '\n+', ' ')
```

```
[1] "hello i am a dog"
```

Comment: stringr is a great package for handling strings with very intuitively named functions. For more help on problems like these, checkout the [stringr cheatsheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/main/strings.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you might find `str_squish()` convenient. This is intended to solve this exact problem, while the other solutions show good ways to solve the more general case.

```r
library(stringr)

mystring = c("hello\n\ni\n\n\n\n\nam\na\n\n\n\n\n\n\ndog")

str_squish(mystring)
# [1] "hello i am a dog"
```

If you look at the code of `str_squish()`, it is basically wrapper around `str_replace_all()`.

```r
str_squish
function (string) 
{
    stri_trim_both(str_replace_all(string, "\\s+", " "))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `stringr::str_squish`:

```r
library(stringr)

str_squish(mystring)

#> [1] "hello i am a dog"
```